# Controls events causes memory leaks?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Can a subscription to an event cause a memory leak?

That is, if in a given page I do

```
public TestPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    myButton.Click += MyButton_Click;

}

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

Do I need to call

```
myButton.Click += MyButton_Click;
```

If yes, where should I call it?

Comment: A subscription to an event actually keeps your object alive. Since that when the event is invoked, your class needs to be alive in order to run it's registered delegate.

Comment: You could subscribe to the event in the OnNavigatedTo and unsubscribe -= in the OnNavigatedFrom may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, when the page is out of scope, the CLR will mark it, including its event handlers, as ready for garbage collection. You do not need to unregister event handlers in your pages.

The situation is different when the event handlers are in *other* objects than the object that raises the event. In the example that you give, that is not the case.

If the object that subscribes to another object's event goes out of scope first, it must unsubscribe from the event handlers or it will actually only be marked for garbage collection when the event source also goes out of scope.

If the object that raises the event goes out of scope first, there is no problem because the subscriptions will also go out of scope.